# Javascript Invalid Argument?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript so please bear with me. I'm working on a custom WYSIWYG editor (no I do not want to use an already made one so please don't suggest it).

I'm having trouble getting it to work in Internet Explorer. It gives me an Invalid Arguement error on lines such as the following:

```
document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, "false");
```

Here is the complete script:

```
function textstyle(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
}

function option(a,b) {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand(a, false, b);
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
}

function button(a) {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand(a, false, null);
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
}

var colorSelection;

function selectColor(selection) {
    colorSelection = selection;
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.left = 0 + document.getElementById(selection).offsetLeft + "px";
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.top = 0 + document.getElementById(selection).offsetTop + document.getElementById(selection).offsetHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.visibility = 'visible';
    return;
}

function changeColor(colorCode) {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand(colorSelection, false, colorCode);
    document.getElementById('colorSelector').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.focus();
    return;
}

function dismissmenu()
{
    document.getElementById("colorSelector").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("fontlist").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("formatlist").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("sizelist").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function Start() {
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
    document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, "false");

    try {
        document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.execCommand("undo", false, null);
        editormode = "true";
    }  catch (e) {
        editormode = "false";
    }

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.addEventListener("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.addEventListener("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.addEventListener("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.attachEvent("mouseup", dismissmenu, true);
        document.attachEvent("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
        document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.document.attachEvent("keypress", dismissmenu, true);
    }
}

function switchEditorMode() {
    if (editormode == "true") {

        var replaceTagsByMode = function(html, editormode) {
            var tags = {};
            for (var i=0, a=['b', 'i', 'u', 'strike', 'sub', 'sup']; i<a.length; i++) {
                tags[['<', a[i], '>'].join('')] = ['[', a[i], ']'].join('');
                tags[['</', a[i], '>'].join('')] = ['[/', a[i], ']'].join('');
            }
            for (var html_tag in tags) {
                if (tags.hasOwnProperty(html_tag)) {
                    html = html.replace.apply(
                    html, editormode ? [html_tag, tags[html_tag], 'g'] : [tags[html_tag], html_tag, 'g']);
                }
            }
            return html;
        };

        var editor_body = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.body;
        editor_body.innerHTML = replaceTagsByMode(editor_body.innerHTML, editormode);


        editormode = "false";

    } else {

        var replaceTagsByMode = function(html, editormode) {
            var tags = {};
            for (var i=0, a=['b', 'i', 'u', 'strike', 'sub', 'sup']; i<a.length; i++) {
                tags[['[', a[i], ']'].join('')] = ['<', a[i], '>'].join('');
                tags[['[/', a[i], ']'].join('')] = ['</', a[i], '>'].join('');
            }
            for (var html_tag in tags) {
                if (tags.hasOwnProperty(html_tag)) {
                    html = html.replace.apply(
                    html, editormode ? [html_tag, tags[html_tag], 'g'] : [tags[html_tag], html_tag, 'g']);
                }
            }
            return html;
        };

        var editor_body = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document.body;
        editor_body.innerHTML = replaceTagsByMode(editor_body.innerHTML, editormode);


        editormode = "true";

    }
}
```

Comment: `please bare with me` I'm sorry but I don't think we're ready for that step just yet.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on MSDN, it appears that `StyleWithCSS` is not a [command identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049.aspx) that exists.

Comment: I see. I went by some information on this guide.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

I may have to detect if browser is FF than style with HTML

Comment: @Cory: don't try to detect FF. Use instead "feature detection" http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/

Comment: Oded is correct, "StyleWithCSS" was introduced by Mozilla and has not been implemented in IE. You could easily feature detect it by surrounding a call to the command with a `try...catch`.